# In Shell Script SSH connection is working only for first line data in CSV file and command failing for remaining servers

Tags: shell-script, ssh, csv, sshpass

My target is to just validate the login is successful for list of servers in CSV file. For SSH Password, Userid and IP address, I am passing these values via CSV.

And want to capture the result of SSH Connection output  after each successful SSH login.

Wrote a shell script for that but, I am seeing successful login output for only the first data set from the CSV. For rest of the servers SSH command is failing.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=Test_data.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read ip user pass
do
sshpass -p $pass ssh -n -t -t -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $user@$ip >> output.txt
wait
exit
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Output:

```
Welcome to CYBER SECURITY
Cisco Codec Release ce 9.12.3 140cd8212ba 2020-04-17
SW Release Date: 2020-04-17
*r Login successful
OK
^[[?1034h10.xx.xx.xx,admin,432584
Command not recognized.
10.xx.xx.xx,admin,432584
Command not recognized.
10.xx.xx.xx,admin,432584
Command not recognized.
10.xx.xx.xx,admin,432584
Command not recognized.
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: SSH shell scripting *does not* work the way you're expecting and that's causing your script to break.

What's happening is obvious: The 'first' SSH connection is established, and from that point on everything that's coming from `stdin` is sent to the SSH connection -- and the Cisco has no idea what to do with a 'command' that's a CSV line.

From the `ssh` manpage:

```
SYNOPSIS
     ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
         [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-L address]
         [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
         [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

That `[command]` bit is key here -- if you want to automate something on the other end of the link, you're going to have to specify it *on the same command line* or it's not part of the `ssh` command. `wait` and `exit` in your script never get called.

Try modifying the line to

```
sshpass -p $pass ssh -n -t -t -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $user@$ip 'wait; exit' >> output.txt
```

and see if that works, although frankly I'd recommend setting them up in an [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) inventory instead; it might save you a hell of a lot of headaches because then you can just run `ansible -m ping ciscos` and get a lovely summary.